# Using a variable within a calc() function

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I feel like I've tried everything, but I just can't seem to get this working. I have a variable called 't' that stores the value of $mobile_menu_height. This value is currently set to 280px;

```
var t = "<?php $mobile_menu_height ?>";  //this is currently 280px
```

Further down in the script I would like to get rid of the hard coded "288px" (I will leave 8px hardcoded) in this line

```
y.style.height = "calc(100vh - 288px)";
```

and instead be using the variable (I've tried using 't' and '$mobile_menu_height' but I can't get either to work in my calc() function. Ideally it would look something like this:

```
y.style.height = "calc(100vh - 8px - t)";
```

or

```
y.style.height = "calc(100vh - 8px - $mobile_menu_height)";
```

But I am simply stuck on how to get this working. Could it possibly be an issue with WordPress sanitization (or lack thereof) of the input of $mobile_menu_height? I have tried inputing both with and without the "px" measurement ie "280" and "280px".

Full script I am working on here:

```
    <script>
        function toggleMobileNav() {
            var x = document.getElementById("container-mobile-menu");
            var y = document.getElementById("content-container");
            var t = "<?php $mobile_menu_height ?>";

            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
                y.style.top = t;
                y.style.height = "calc(100vh - 288px)";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
                y.style.top = "62px";
                y.style.height = "calc(100vh - 68px)";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the string? You should also strongly consider meaningful variable names - variables that are single letters are very difficult to make sense of

Comment: You need to echo the value: `<?php echo $mobile_menu_height ?>` or it will simply result in an empty string in your js-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.innerHeight` to get the 100vh equivalent and manually compute like so

```
const windowH = window.innerHeight + 8 + parseInt(t);
y.style.height = windowH + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! It used a combination of your answers to fix things. I was indeed missing an echo, and the window.innerHeight worked like magic. I'll clean up those variable names now. Fixed code here for those wondering.

```
    <?php
        $mobile_menu_height = get_theme_mod( 'mobile_menu_height_setting', '' );
    ?>
    <script>
        function toggleMobileNav() {
            var x = document.getElementById("container-mobile-menu");
            var y = document.getElementById("content-container");
            var mobile_menu_content_drop = "<?php echo $mobile_menu_height; ?>";
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
                y.style.top = mobile_menu_content_drop;
                const windowH = window.innerHeight - 8 - parseInt(mobile_menu_content_drop);
                y.style.height = windowH + "px";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
                y.style.top = "62px";
                y.style.height = "calc(100vh - 68px)";
            }
        }
    </script>
```